# Execute Function until Predicate is Satisfied

Tags: coffeescript

I'm trying to write a function, `doAndRepeatUntil` that calls a function `f` until a predicate/condition `pred` is true.

In the following code, I would expect `@sum` to start at 0, and then print `10, 20, ..., 90, 100` and then terminate.

```
doAndRepeatUntil = (f, pred) ->
  console.log @sum
  f() until pred()

@sum = 0

f = ->
  @sum += 10

pred = ->
  @sum >= 100

console.log f() # NaN

doAndRepeatUntil(f, pred) # infinite loop
```

However, I'm seeing `f()` print out `NaN`. And `doAndRepeatUntil(f,pred)` spins in an infinite loop.

Comment: Are you sure `@` is what you think it is everywhere you're using it?

Comment: no I'm not apparently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short) hinted at in his comment, `@sum` has a different `this` context in each function. If you situation allows, I would define `sum` before the functions so that it is in scope for all of them ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maxbeatty/2j4WZ/)).

```
sum = 0

doAndRepeatUntil = (f, pred) ->
  console.log sum
  f() until pred()

f = ->
  console.log 'f', sum
  sum += 10

pred = ->
  console.log 'pred', sum
  sum >= 100

doAndRepeatUntil f, pred # infinite loop
```

If you do need to keep `@sum`, then you'll need to use a fat arrow on the functions ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maxbeatty/2j4WZ/1/)).

```
@sum = 0

doAndRepeatUntil = (f, pred) =>
  console.log @sum
  f() until pred()

f = =>
  console.log 'f', @sum
  @sum += 10

pred = =>
  console.log 'pred', @sum
  @sum >= 100

doAndRepeatUntil f, pred # infinite loop
```

Comment: You could also use `f.sum = 0` and `f.pred = -> ...` as an easy way to collect the parts together (remember that you can attach properties to pretty much anything you want in (Coffee|Java)Script). Or create a quick class to collect `sum`, `f`, and `pred` into one package.